# disable or suspend flymake when visiting file with merge conflicts

Tags: emacs, flymake

When opening a file with unresolved merge conflicts in it, Emacs enable smerge-mode by default along with other modes (in this case Python mode + EGlot and friends). This triggers Flymake to run as well which complains about the merge conflict headers added by the source control or diff tool.

[image: just after Emacs has loaded with a file with merge issues]

When disabling flymake the errors naturally disappears

[image: flymake manually disabled]

However, when enabling flymake again, it shows no syntax errors. Just a 'Wait'.
Maybe flymake is aware of smerge-mode or similar after it has been enabled?

[image]

Have anyone configured their Emacs in such a way to disable flymake-mode when visiting a file with merge conflics (smerge-mode) and 'heavy' modes like eglot, or do you know if flymake is smart enough to detect this?

I have experimented with some elisp to detect smerge-mode on different hooks and disable flymake accordingly, but it leaves the buffer face 'dirty/damaged' with flymakes error marks around the text.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, prefer code than image please : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: I have no code to demonstrate this. The images are there to help give a visual idea of what is happening, as the link you posted states: 

"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that can't be made clear in any other way, such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."